# How to resize figure box in a two-column BioMed Central LaTex template?

Tags: graphics, floats, templates

I am using a {twocolumn} document class in the BioMed Central LaTex template and need to create figures with different sizes (e.g., one-column and two-column). In this template, figures come inside a box. The regular graphics control only resizes the image inside the box but the box size stays intact. Also, the resized image overlaps with the text in the other column. Here is the problem:[image]

And here is how I added the figure in the Tex file:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=1.2\columnwidth]{tree.png}
        \caption{---------}
        \label{fig:1}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{1em}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What is the result using `width=0.5\textwidth`?

Comment: It works the same way: only changes the size of the figure, not the box. There are lower-level controls over figures in the local .cls file that I don't know how two use them.

Comment: Could you post a complete minimal example that start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`?

Comment: Use `\begin{figure*}[h!]`. The wide figures will go in the next page.

Comment: @SimonDispa, thank you! It resolved the issue. Could you explain the use of an asterisk? I know that the exclamation mark overrides the internal parameters.

Comment: Please see the end of my answer.  The asterisk used in environments (like `\chapter*` ) is  call `star`. It serves to have an alternative behavior for the same command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\begin{figure*}` for wide boxed figures. They will usually land in the next page.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{bmcart}% 
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support

\usepackage{graphicx} % needed <<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text

\begin{document}    

\begin{frontmatter}

%\begin{fmbox}
\dochead{Research}

\title{A sample article title}

\author[
  addressref={aff1},                   % id's of addresses, e.g. {aff1,aff2}
  corref={aff1},                       % id of corresponding address, if any
% noteref={n1},                        % id's of article notes, if any
  email={jane.e.doe@cambridge.co.uk}   % email address
]{\inits{J.E.}\fnm{Jane E.} \snm{Doe}}
\author[
  addressref={aff1,aff2},
  email={john.RS.Smith@cambridge.co.uk}
]{\inits{J.R.S.}\fnm{John R.S.} \snm{Smith}}    

\address[id=aff1]{%                           % unique id
  \orgdiv{Department of Science},             % department, if any
  \orgname{University of Cambridge},          % university, etc
  \city{London},                              % city
  \cny{UK}                                    % country
}
\address[id=aff2]{%
  \orgdiv{Institute of Biology},
  \orgname{National University of Sciences},
  %\street{},
  %\postcode{}
  \city{Kiel},
  \cny{Germany}
}
    
%\end{fmbox}% comment this for two column layout    

\begin{abstractbox}

\begin{abstract} % abstract
\parttitle{First part title} %if any
Text for this section.

\parttitle{Second part title} %if any
Text for this section.
\end{abstract}
    
\begin{keyword}
\kwd{sample}
\kwd{article}
\kwd{author}
\end{keyword}   

\end{abstractbox}   

\end{frontmatter}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section*{Content}
Text and results for this section, as per the individual journal's instructions for authors.

\section*{Section title}

\textbf{>>>FIGURE 1 INSERTED HERE <<<}

\begin{figure*}[h!] % use figure* for wide boxed figures
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption{Sample figure title a}
    \label{fig:example-image-a}
\end{figure*}

In this section we examine the growth rate of the mean of $Z_0$, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$. In
addition, we examine a common modeling assumption and note the
importance of considering the tails of the extinction time $T_x$ in
studies of escape dynamics.
We will first consider the expected resistant population at $vT_x$ for
some $v>0$, (and temporarily assume $\alpha=0$)
%
\[
E \bigl[Z_1(vT_x) \bigr]=
\int_0^{v\wedge
1}Z_0(uT_x)
\exp (\lambda_1)\,du .
\]
%
If we assume that sensitive cells follow a deterministic decay
$Z_0(t)=xe^{\lambda_0 t}$ and approximate their extinction time as
$T_x\approx-\frac{1}{\lambda_0}\log x$, then we can heuristically
estimate the expected value as
%
\begin{equation}\label{eqexpmuts}
\begin{aligned}[b]
&      E\bigl[Z_1(vT_x)\bigr]\\
&\quad      = \frac{\mu}{r}\log x
\int_0^{v\wedge1}x^{1-u}x^{({\lambda_1}/{r})(v-u)}\,du .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
%
Thus we observe that this expected value is finite for all $v>0$.

\section*{Availability of data and materials}%% if any
1. \kant[1-4]

\section*{Ethics approval and consent to participate}

\textbf{>>>FIGURE 2 INSERTED HERE <<<}

\begin{figure*}[h!] % use figure* for wide boxed  figures
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
        \caption{Sample figure title b}
    \label{fig:example-image-b}
\end{figure*}

2. \kant[2-6]

\end{document}
```

The `bmcart` class sets its own figure settings: font, space above and bellow, ...

```
\def\figure@settings{%
  \let\textbf\fig@textbf%
  \setattribute{floatcaption}{size}{\footnotesize\sffamily\raggedright}
  \if@figurestar\hsize=\textwidth\fi% <<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \@tempdima\hsize%
  \advance\@tempdima by-\figure@sep%
  \advance\@tempdima by-\figure@sep%
  \hsize\@tempdima%
  \parindent\z@%
  \centering%
  \setlength\abovecaptionskip{6\p@}%
  \setlength\belowcaptionskip{0\p@}%
}
```

Finding `\begin{figure*}` sets the figure width to `\textwidth`.